# Optimized way to draw curved line (1000 dots) on a bitmap

Tags: c#

Is there an optimized way to pass a buffer of points that will draw a single curved line on an bitmap or do we have the repeatedly call the same pixel call 1000 times?

Comment: Check out GraphicsPath

Comment: What do you use to draw ?

Comment: Obtain a Graphic object from the bitmap: `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);` and then: `g.DrawCurve(...);` or `g.DrawArc(...);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using winform (do you?) and your points are in an array

```
PointF[] myPoints = // wherever your data come from.;
```

you can pump them into a GraphicsPath like this:

```
 GraphicsPath outPath = new GraphicsPath(//your.FillMode);
 outPath.AddLines(myPoints );
```

and have them drawn in a Paint event:

```
 G.DrawPath(yourPen, outPath);
```

This will draw a PolyLine through all your points with a chosen pen.
For a truely curved line you could directly use DrawCurve (like LarsTech wrote):

```
 G.DrawCurve(yourPen, myPoints );
```

If you want to actually plot the points you will have to write the code yourself. Make sure to look up `lockbits` if you do, to get something remotely like 'performance' out of winforms..

Comment: Great, I'll look into this ASAP.

Comment: This seems to work but it draws from 0.0. Is there a way to tell him to draw from certain coordinates ?

Comment: Which one have you tried? Both G.DrawCurve and G.DrawPath simply ought to connect the points you feed in. Are you sure the first point isn't (0,0)? All coordinates are relative to the Control of the Graphics.

Comment: Your answer solved my problem. What I was referring on the last comment is that I needed to use Matrix.Transformation in order to position the actual Curve on the spot where I wanted.